# Why does a query in mongodb run only for exaclty 3600s and then stops without any logs?

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I use a find command to parse my initial json files into a new collection. All works really great but it stops at exactly 3600s. It is not a hardware issue since I tried on two different machines.
I use a
    db.collection.find().forEach( function ... command.

I use robomongo as a temporary gui.

EDIT: I also have the following entry in my logs
["[conn557392] killcursors: found 0 of 1" in Mongodb replication primary log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729358/conn557392-killcursors-found-0-of-1-in-mongodb-replication-primary-log)

EDIT: Solved! This seems to be a problem with robomong. Works fine in the normal mongo shell.

Comment: Sounds like a timeout/time-limit configured on the server.

Comment: I already use find().addOption(DBQuery.Option.noTimeout). And I didn't touch the standard config. Where would I find something like that?